# where are the definition (not declaration) of identifiers stored in a compiler in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I went through a lot of answers on this question,but i am still very much confused.

I understand that header files contains the declaration of identifiers whereas library contains the definition of these? we can access .h file associated within a compiler but how to access library files?

*one more question*

we include only header files within our program,then how library files get linked to it?

Comment: the information in libraries is stored as binary data, you can't easily look at the definitions once it has been compiled.

Comment: You can't access the soucecode of a library directly because its precomiled. But the library code is often availble online

Comment: I think you're confusing identifiers (names) with the things they identify (types, namespaces, variables, functions, ...).

Comment: @molbdnilo sir, what do we call the "things" they identify?

Comment: you need the full source code of the library. If the library is entirely defined with header files (template based libraries for example) then your .h file declares and defines the whole library. Else you need the original source code that was used to build the compiled library (a binary file).

Comment: @vibhanshukumar We call them (for example) types, or namespaces, or variables, or functions. The term "identifier" essentially means "a sequence of characters that can be used as a name for something".

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to illustrate with an example

header.h

```
int func(int in);
```

a.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int b = func(2);
    return 0;
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
int func(int in)
{
    return in*2;
}
```

Now let's compile

```
g++ -c -o a.o  a.cpp
```

and we can take a look at the symbol table of the generated object-file

```
objdump -t a.o

a.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 a.cpp
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame      0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000023 main
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _Z4funci
```

So there we see the main function defined in a.cpp and we also see an entry called `_Z4funci` (this is what identifies "func") but it is marked as undefined (the `*UND*` before the address). So the linker will later look for it in another object.

Now let's look at b

```
g++ -c -o b.o  b.cpp
objdump -t a.o

b.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 b.cpp
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame      0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000e _Z4funci
```

There's the definition for `_Z4funci`

and now you can link the two together to create the complete executable object

```
g++ a.o b.o -o out
./out
```

If you want to know how `_Z4funci` is the name that's decided on, read up on "C++ name-mangling"

Answer (score -3):

use cscope tool to find out the library files .

cmd 1 : ctags -uR
cmd 2 : cscope -uRC

Select option according to stuffs you want to search , you can find defination of functions , functions calling by another functions , library files ,source code and much more .

Note : It is according to Linux OS.

Comment: this still requires you to actually HAVE the sourcecode as uncompiled text somewhere. If all you have is a library file, this won't help at all.